# Unpivoting data in google sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, unpivot

I have the following data in Excel:

[image]

How do I unpivot the above into the following in Excel or Google Sheets?

[image]

Comment: Hi please do not share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead. This is more likely to encourage users to answer since it is easier to replicate what you have.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: if below answer solved your question, please toggle checkmark to accept it

Answer (score 0):

in excel, bring the data into powerquery with data ... from table/range.... [x] headers

go into home advanced editor and use

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content], //replace this row with the autogenerated row excel provides
base_columns=1, groupsof=3, 
Combo = List.Transform(List.Split(List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base_columns),groupsof), each List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base_columns) & _),
#"Added Custom" =List.Accumulate(Combo, #table({"Column1"}, {}),(state,current)=> state & Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source, current)),1))
in #"Added Custom"
```

file .. close and load ... as table or pivot back to excel

Alternate for preserving row sort

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content], //replace this row with the autogenerated row excel provides
#"Changed Type" =  Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),
leading=1, groupsof=3,
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.Split( List.RemoveFirstN(Record.ToList( _),leading), groupsof) ),
#"Added Custom0" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom0", each Text.Combine(List.FirstN(Record.ToList(_),leading),"|")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom0",{"Custom0", "Custom"}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn( #"Removed Other Columns", "Custom"),
#"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "|"), type text}),
#"Merged Columns" = if leading=0 then Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Custom0"}) else Table.CombineColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Custom0", "Custom"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None),"Custom"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Merged Columns", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),leading+groupsof))
in #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]